# Stacked Bar Chart Labels-- Using geom_text to label % on a value based y-axis

Tags: ggplot2, geom-text

I am looking to create a stacked bar chart where my y-axis measures the value but the table shows the % of total bar.

I think I need to add a pct column to my table then use that but am not sure how to get the pct column either.

Df for example is: 
date, type, value, pct
Jan 1, A, 5, **45% (5/11)**
Jan 1, B, 6, **55% (6/11)**

[table and chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHErd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
test.df <- data.frame(date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02"),
                      type = c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
                      val = c(5:6, 1, 7))

test.df <- test.df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(
    type.num = as.numeric(type),
    prop = val/sum(val),
    y_text_pos = ifelse(type=="B", val, sum(val))) %>%
  ungroup()


ggplot(data = test.df, aes(x = as.Date(date), y = val, fill = type)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(y = y_text_pos, label = paste0(round(prop*100,1), "%")), color = "black", vjust = 1.1)
```

With the output:
[image]